# How do I apply a wholesale group price with the Extended Pricing Module?

Tags: php, silverstripe, silvershop

When using the Extended pricing module I add the following to my YML file.

```
Product:
  extensions:
    - HasGroupPricing
HasGroupPricing:
  price_levels:
    wholesale: WholesalePrice
  field_labels:
    WholesalePrice: 'Price for wholesale customers'
```

I have a wholesale group and the fields show up in the CMS for setting a price, but nothing happens on the front end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key for the `price_levels` has to *exactly* match the `Code` of the group in the CMS. The `Code` of a group will only be set with the initial write, so renaming a group later on won't change its group-code!

That being said, you should inspect the `Group` Table in your Database and look at the `Code` column. Identify the group you want to apply the `WholesalePrice` to and ensure that the key matches the `Code` of that group…

Example: You have a Group that is called "My Wholesale Group", the `Code` of said group is `my-group` (you'd have to look this up in the Database). You'd then have to change your YML to read:

```
HasGroupPricing:
  price_levels:
    # Here's where we change the key to match the Group Code
    my-group: WholesalePrice 
  field_labels:
    WholesalePrice: 'Price for wholesale customers'
```

Comment: Ah, that's probably it. I changed the name of the group to wholesale. I'll let you know shortly if this solves the issue.